# ASP Session ID missing from GET request for only one user while accessing Forefront UAG published application

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, cookies

Here is the scenario:

A client has a fairly standard IIS site published via a UAG portal trunk. Clicking the link on the portal page from an external client is supposed to effect a redirect to said IIS site, hosted internally. Simple enough.

For every single domain user except *one*, this works just fine. Here is the output from a successful redirect:

> GET
>
> /uniquesig6192b908e3f362bf06404502c58f28f18ec5923ef22832661845904b888b6fc7/uniquesig1/[sitename]/[appdirectory]/[resource].aspx
>
> HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */* Referer:
>   https://portal.[company].com/[appdirectory]/Pages/[resource].aspx
>   Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0) Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Host:
>   [othersubdomain].[company].com
>
> DNT: 1 
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> **Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId= r5uavyvx0drz42453cml4055;
>   __utma=128077646.1396813579.1381846816.1381846816.1381846816.1;**

However, there is a single AD user that does not successfully redirect, regardless of browser, OS, location, ISP, you name it. We had them recreate the user in AD to create a different descriptor and verify that user object wasn't corrupt somehow. When the 'bad' user attempts to click the redirect link, the following GET request is generated:

> GET
>
> /uniquesig6192b908e3f362bf06404502c58f28f18ec5923ef22832661845904b888b6fc7/uniquesig1/[sitename]/[appdirectory]/[resource].aspx
>
> HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */* Referer:
>   https://portal.[company].com/[appdirectory]/Pages/[resource].aspx
>   Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;
>   Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0) Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Host:
>   [othersubdomain].[company].com
>
> DNT: 1 
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> **Cookie: __utma=128077646.1396813579.1381846816.1381846816.1381846816.1;**

As you can see, the ASPNet session ID cookie is never sent to authenticate with IIS. at first, I thought it might be an affinity problem, wherein a cookie is not recognized due to load balancing; however, we drain-stopped one server to ensure that traffic was only authenticating on one box. ASP.NET cookies are issued by IIS, which again, would indicate a potential issue with IIS. However, again, it is confined to a single user. Another possibility is that the user has Logon Permitted hours incorrectly set, which might deny them that session ID cookie from IIS. According to the client, no dice.

Can anyone see anything I might be missing? Thanks!